# NSGridView difficulties

Tags: swift, macos, nsview

I'm using an `NSGridView` in the settings panel for my macOS app. I set it up like this:

```
class GeneralViewController: RootViewController {
    private var gridView: NSGridView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let restaurantLabel = NSTextField()
        restaurantLabel.stringValue = "Restaurant"

        let restaurantButton = NSPopUpButton()
        restaurantButton.addItems(withTitles: ["A", "B", "C"])

        let updatesLabel = NSTextField()
        updatesLabel.stringValue = "Updates"
        updatesLabel.isEditable = false
        updatesLabel.isBordered = false
        updatesLabel.isBezeled = false

        let updatesButton = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Automatically pull in updates from WordPress", target: nil, action: nil)

        let empty = NSGridCell.emptyContentView
        gridView = NSGridView(views: [
            [restaurantLabel, restaurantButton],
            [updatesLabel, updatesButton]
            ])
        gridView?.wantsLayer = true
        gridView?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        gridView?.column(at: 0).xPlacement = .trailing
        gridView?.rowAlignment = .firstBaseline
        gridView?.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 600), for: .horizontal)
        gridView?.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 600), for: .vertical)

        view.addSubview(gridView!)
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        super.viewDidLayout()

        gridView?.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this, the `NSGridView` fills up the whole view, but the checkbox is really off. As you can see in the image.

Also, I'd love for the content to not fill the whole cell, making it all look a tad more centered.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you change the row alignment to `.lastBaseline` it will fix your issue of the vertical alignment of the `NSButton` and the `NSTextField`. If you want more spacing (I'm guessing that's what you mean with "I'd love for the content to not fill the whole cell"), you can use the `columnSpacing` and `rowSpacing` properties of the `NSGridView`. If you then also add instances of `NSGridCell.emptyContentView` around your "real" content, you should be able to achieve the following effect.
[image]

This is new code after the changes I suggested:

```
class GeneralViewController: RootViewController {
    private var gridView: NSGridView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let restaurantLabel = NSTextField()
        restaurantLabel.stringValue = "Restaurant"

        let restaurantButton = NSPopUpButton()
        restaurantButton.addItems(withTitles: ["A", "B", "C"])

        let updatesLabel = NSTextField()
        updatesLabel.stringValue = "Updates"
        updatesLabel.isEditable = false
        updatesLabel.isBordered = false
        updatesLabel.isBezeled = false

        let updatesButton = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Automatically pull in updates from WordPress", target: nil, action: nil)

        let empty = NSGridCell.emptyContentView
        gridView = NSGridView(views: [
            [empty],
            [empty, restaurantLabel, restaurantButton, empty],
            [empty, updatesLabel, updatesButton, empty],
            [empty],
            [empty]
        ])
        gridView?.wantsLayer = true
        gridView?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        gridView?.column(at: 0).xPlacement = .trailing
        gridView?.rowAlignment = .lastBaseline
        gridView?.columnSpacing = 20
        gridView?.rowSpacing = 20
                gridView?.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 600), for: .horizontal)
        gridView?.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 600), for: .vertical)

        view.addSubview(gridView!)
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        super.viewDidLayout()

        gridView?.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```